# what do these commands do in the digits dataset clustering demonstration?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, k-means

I have been looking at this fitting a digits dataset to a k-means cluster on Python tutorial [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.11-k-means.html), and some of the codes are just confusing me.

I do understand this part where we need to train our model using 10 clusters.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
digits.data.shape

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10, random_state=0)
clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(digits.data)
kmeans.cluster_centers_.shape
```

The following show us an output of the 10 cluster centroids on the console.
it first creates figure and axes which has two row, each row has 5 axes subplots return the figure and
(8,3) is the size of the figure displaying on the console.
But after that I just do not understand how the command shows the output of cluster centroids in the for loop.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 5, figsize=(8, 3))
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_.reshape(10, 8, 8)
for axi, center in zip(ax.flat, centers):
    axi.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])
    axi.imshow(center, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.binary)
```

Also, this part is to check how accurate the clustering was in finding the similar digits within the data.  I know that we need to create a labels that has the same size as the clusters filling with zero so we can place our predicted label in there.
But again, I just do not understand how do they implement it inside the for-loop.

```
from scipy.stats import mode
labels = np.zeros_like(clusters)
for i in range(10):
    mask = (clusters == i)
    labels[mask] = mode(digits.target[mask])[0]
```

Can someone please explain what each line of the commands do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question 1: How does the code plot the centroids?

It's important to see that each centroid is a point in the feature space. In other words, a centroid looks like one of the training samples. In this case, each training sample is an 8 × 8 image (although they've been flattened into rows with 64 elements (because `sklearn` always wants input `X` to be a two-dimensional array). So each centroid also represents an 8 × 8 image.

The loop steps over the axes (a 2 × 5 matrix) and the centroids (`kmeans.cluster_centers_` together. The purpose of `zip` is to ensure that for each `Axes` object there is a corresponding `center` (this is a common way to plot a bunch of *n* things into a bunch of *n* subplots). The centroids have been reshaped into a 10 × 8 × 8 array, so that each of the 10 centroids is the 8 × 8 image we're expecting.

Since each centroid is now a 2D array, you can use `imshow` to plot it.

#### Question 2: How does the code assign labels?

The easiest thing might be to take the code apart and run bits of it on their own. For example, take a look at `clusters == 0`. This is a Boolean array. You can use Boolean arrays to index other arrays of the same shape. The first line of code in the loop assigns this array to `mask` so we can use it.

Then we index into `labels` using the Boolean array (try it!) to say, "Change these values to the mode average of the corresponding elements of the label vector, i.e. `digits.target`." The index `[0]` is just needed because of what the [`scipy.stats.mode()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) function returns (again, try it out).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! the explanation regarding Question 2 is absolutely spot on! but I am still a bit confused about question 1. especially the zip function, I still don't quite understand this line: ```for axi, center in zip(ax.flat, centers):``` why do we need to zip ax.flat and centers in here?

Comment: @randomguy I edited my answer. The reason for `ax.flat` is that `plt.subplots(2, 5)` gives a 2 &times; 5 array, so this must be flattened in order to maintain a 1:1 correspondence with the centers when iterating. Probably `axs` would be a better name for the array of `Axes`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, now I completely understand what's going on in here!